# Run ssh daemon in different namespace to connected clients

Tags: ssh, networking, sshd, namespace, network-namespaces

If `sshd` is running in the (non-init) namespace of the appropriate physical device:

```
ip netns exec physical sshd
```

is it possible to have clients that connect on that interface get a shell with the different default namespace (the init namespace in my case)?

As it is, client commands run as if `ip netns exec physical <cmd>` - which of course makes sense, but isn't what I want in this case.

Answer (score 2):

Ah, I found a solution: `netns` stores its known namespaces in `/var/run/netns/`; these are nothing other than namespace files (`man namespaces`) in `/proc/<PID>/ns/`.

So, we can add the init namespace there, even though it's usually absent:

```
ln -s /proc/1/ns/net /var/run/netns/init
```

Then, we can force clients to open a shell in that namespace when they connect, with an option to `sshd`:

```
-o ForceCommand='sudo ip netns exec init sudo /bin/bash --login'
```

And thus the daemon still runs in the specified non-init namespace, but clients connect and immediately enter the init (PID 1) network namespace.

---

N.B.
We can also keep the connecting user instead of jumping to root(!), and use `getent passwd` to retrieve their usual login shell:

```
# instead of sudo /bin/bash
# *important*: we give ForceCommand='' in *single* quotes
#     so `whomai` et al. are not evaluated until the ForceCommand is invoked.
sudo --user="$(whoami)" "$(getent passwd "$(whoami)" | cut -d: -f7)"
```

and keep any command supplied by the client (`ssh user@host cmd`) by pulling it from `$SSH_ORIGINAL_COMMAND` at the front of the command.